# plot tuple values from a dictionary scatter plot

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, plot, tuples

I'll be more specific: I have a dictionary

```
dict{'A':(0,1), 'B':(2,3), 'C':(4,5)}
```

where the keys and values have the form `'key':(x,y)`

I am trying to generate a scatter plot where the key is the point in the graph (preferably labeled), located at x in x axis and with y in y axis.

This of course for every key-value pair in the dictionary.

so far I have just some plot parameters as written code, and am struggling to figure out how to access the key values for every key.

```
    ### Plot Parameters ###
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 'x-large'
plt.rcParams["axes.titlesize"] = 'x-large'
plt.rcParams["xtick.labelsize"] = 'x-large'
plt.rcParams["ytick.labelsize"] = 'x-large'

    for i in dict.values():
       x = i[1]
   ...:y = i[0]

    plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color='black')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Im looking into a for loop but that would just make a different plot for every key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = {'A':(0,1), 'B':(2,3), 'C':(4,5)}

for i in t:
    (x, y) = t.get(i)
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.text(x=x, y=y, s=i)

plt.show()
```

hope this helps you

Comment: I see, my problem is putting those i in dict.values as points in a scatterplot without creating a scatter plot for every i. Unless the most effective way is to not use a dictionary?

Comment: do you want to make a list of values of dict or what?

Comment: plot a graph where the key is a point, and its coordinates for the x and y axis are the values in the corresponding tuple (x,y). evey key in the dictionary is a point in the plot. Im sorry if Im not being clear, I am still a beginner.

Comment: I have edited the answer try that if it helps you.
if it also don't help you please let me know

Comment: Please accept the answer and vote it up if your problem is resolved

Comment: Can't vote up yet! apparently need more rep in this site